# Анимации на события

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация, события, animate

Как мне прикрепить разные анимации к разным событиям? Одну например на нажатие button, другую на переключение checkbox, другую просто на наведение button.

Comment: Просто использовать [EventTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @icebat Отлично, подходит, а вы напишите это как ответ, чтобы было видно, что проблема решена .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Специально для этого существуют [EventTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-ы:

> Represents a trigger that applies a set of actions in response to an
>   event.

Указанная статья на msdn содержит и примеры.
Также есть [русская версия](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.eventtrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).